# Determining the number of walks in a special matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

We are given that $G = (V,E)$ is a graph with $|V| < \infty, V = \{(i,j) | 1 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq j \leq 1\}$ where $n \geq 3$.  Next we are given that if we have two vertices $x,y$ where $x = (a,b), y = (c,d)$, then $E(x,y) = 0 \ \text{if} \ b = d$, 
$E(x,y) = 1 \ \text{if} \ a = c, b \neq d$, and $E(x,y) = 2 \ \text{otherwise}$.  We are asked to give a formula for the number of walks of length $l, l \geq 1$ from $x \in V$ to $y \in V$.  I know that we can raise the adjancency matrix to the power of $l$ for walks of length $l$, but I am having a trouble discerning the pattern that happens with the entries when doing so for this specific matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a combinatorial approach: Suppose you visit vertices $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_k$ with $x_1=x,x_k=y,$ and $x_i\neq x_j$ for any $i\neq j.$ Then you need to know how many times you stay in each vertex and so you are interested in $(\alpha _1,\cdots ,\alpha _k)\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ such that $\sum _{i=1}^k\alpha _i=\ell.$ You can do this in $\binom{\ell -1}{k-1}$ ways. now, every time that you change vertex you paid $2$ and you have $n-1$ options. Can you add over this possibilities of $k$? Notice that you have to distinguish the second component, so the formula depends in if $\ell$ is even or odd and if we start with $b=d$ or not. 
**Edit:** What i wrote was very incomplete. I am sorry for the inconvenience. 
Now, fix $x$ as the vertex and fix a number $k\leq \ell,$ we would like to factor the path as follows: $$P=(x,a_1,\cdots ,a_{k})$$ apriori, forget that we want $a_{k}=y,$ but assume $a_{k}\neq x$ Then, this is like counting the number of closed paths in the complete graph starting and ending at $x$ of length $k +1$ which can be counted or found using the eigenvalues to be $$\frac{(n-1)^{k +1}-(n-1)(-1)^{k}}{n},$$

Now, we are allowing cycles(so notice that the $a_i$ are paths in between elements with the same first coordinate), and so we want to stay in each vertex $a_k$ a time, say $\alpha _i\geq 1.$ So we have a vector $(\alpha _0,\alpha _1,\cdots ,\alpha _k)\in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ such that $\sum _{i=0}^k\alpha _i=\ell+1$ as said before, this can be counted in $\binom{\ell }{k}$ ways. Now, any time that we switch vertex we have $2$ options as the graph has two edges in between these kind of vertices, so we have to pay $2^k.$ Now, by symmetry, going to any of the vertices $\neq x$ should have the same number of paths, and so adding all the possible $k$ we get
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^\ell \binom{\ell}{k}2^k((n-1)^k-(-1)^k)$$
Here i am assuming that the first components of $x$ and $y$ are different. Now we have to take care of the parity and the case in which $x,y$ have same first component. Can you do it?

Comment: Okay so I had been looking at this problem, and had derived that the even or oddness of $l$ mattered and whether or not we had $b = d$ since the resulting graph is bipartite.I am not sure what you mean by "you paid 2" though.

Comment: Also I am not sure what you are saying my sum should be.

Comment: And if I'm reading what you are saying about $\alpha$ then isn't that the number of integer partitions.

Comment: Sorry i have not been clear. I meant you pay $2$ any time that you jump to a vertex of different first component. So the approach is to set how many times this happens in the path and count them individually. I will edit my post to be more clear. Sorry.

Comment: I appreciate that and the more I think about it I think I understand what you are saying somewhat.  Just having trouble hashing out the sums.

Comment: One good question as I think through this more comes up.  How do you track the same first component vertices in the formula?

Comment: Those are counted using the partitions. Each part of the partition tells you how much time you spend in where the first component is equal. I edited with much more detail.

Comment: that is an elegant answer and what you are saying makes much more sense now.  Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: For the parity and case where the component at the beginning is the same, we should just tack on a "$+(-1)^l$" at the end of the equation outside the sum.  I believe this is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101858/discussion-between-ethan-deakins-and-phicar).

Comment: So Phicar I have been going over this for some time. It is correct because you can check it, but I’m rinsed as to the path decompositions.  You say that any time you switch vertices you have two choices but what if the switch is (1,0) —-> (1,1).  In this case we only have one choice so wouldn’t multiplying by two over count?  Again I know you’re correct just trying to get a full understanding of it.  Also why does the exponent go from k+1 in the complete situation to just k in this graph?

Comment: The switch (1,0)->(1,1) is controlled by the $\alpha _i.$ Here $k$ is the number of switches that change first coordinate. The ones that mantain it are counted with the binomial. The exponent is because this formula is used to find closed walks of length $k,$ but closed walks of length $k+1$ are equivalent to non closed paths of length $k$ to any vertex.